# Email regex to allow subdomains

Tags: regex

I have the following Regex: `/^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/`
Basically, it allows an email like contact@admin.mydomain.com or contact@mydomain.uk.com
What I would like to do is prevent the part after the @ sign and before the first dot to start or end with dot. So contact@.admin.mydomain.com and contact@admin.mydomain..com should not be allowed.

I tried this `^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@^(?!\.)[a-zA-Z0-9.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$` but it seems not checking if the part after @ starts or not with dot.
I don't know how to do it as I'm not good with Regexes.

Comment: FWIW, your regex will block a lot of perfectly valid emails. A double dot at the end or a dot after the @ sign is not going to help that much if `email+string@domain.com` doesn't work. Or `москва@москва.рф`. I'd say focus on blocking less *valid* emails before trying to filter invalid ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify your regular expression to ensure that the part after the "@" sign and before the first dot does not start or end with a dot, you need to adjust the pattern to specifically check for this condition. Your initial attempt using ^ inside the square brackets is not the correct approach, as ^ inside square brackets negates the character set, but it doesn't assert position when used this way.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@(?![.])[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+(?<![.])\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$
```

Comment: This still allows other emails that OP might find undesirable like `abc@a....b.com` which is not valid. It technically stilll has a double dot before the TLD. https://regex101.com/r/LON6NZ/1

Comment: Yes you're right.    /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@(?![.])[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?<![.])\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any lookarounds at all, you can take out the dot from the character class after the @ sign like `[a-zA-Z0-9]+`, and optionally repeat a single dot followed by that same character class in a non capture group denoted as `(?:...)*`

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jlCxE5/1)